# Not able to get ng-model value from dynamically created input box

Tags: angularjs

Here is how I am adding fields.

```
$scope.addEmailField = function () {   //Function to add new email field.
    if (valid <= 1 && checkToDelete == 0) {
        var mailTxtId = 'mail' + valid;
        var mailModel = 'Contact_Email' + valid;
        var hide = 'hide' + valid;
        hide = false;
        console.log(mailTxtId);
        var emailDiv = angular.element(document.querySelector('#emailDiv'));
        var element = $compile('<div id="' + mailTxtId + '" style="margin-left: -60px; width:200px; margin-top:15px"><input id= "' + mailModel + '" type = "text" class="form-control" ng-model="' + mailModel + '" ng-blur="validateEmailDynamic(' + valid + ')">' +
            '<input id="' + valid + '" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 206px; width:54px; margin-top:-34px" type="button" value="-" ng-click="deleteField(' + valid + ')"><span ng-show ="' + hide + '" style="color:red">' +
            'Invalid email</span></div>')($scope);
        emailDiv.append(element);

        valid = valid + 1;
    }
};
```

But not getting the value of ng-model.

Comment: Sorry, which jquery tag?, I am getting the div in which I need to add the elements. method (ng-click) is working but ng-model is not .

Comment: Any better way to add elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Store your input box in a directive's template. Then add ng-class that would determine whether it should show or not.

```
app.directive('inputBox', function(){
     template:'<input ng-model="item">'
});
```

Usage in the html:

```
<div ng-class="{ input-box : triggerInputBox }"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.triggerInputBox = true;
```

This is just one of many ways to accomplish this. But directives are very useful for dynamically showing templates.